# Ruby Concurrency in cron job needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, concurrency, cron

I am developing a system in which the API should handle simultaneous, continuous by rails 4.0

In system, each user has 3 scripts to be run in background. The scripts grab the user's information from DB to call API repeatedly and process transaction. Currently I am using cronjob (whenever gem) to run scripts in the background for each individual user

So my problem is when the system has 1,000 people, I need to run 3000 cronjobs.
I think this system will have problems. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps look into the Sidekiq gem... though I'm not sure I understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you have a system that performs some tasks periodically, and the amount of work your system has to handle (let's say, per hour) is less than the amount of work it could handle.

However, the amount of work increases with the number of users in your system so, as you have already guessed, there will be a moment when the situation will be critical. Your system will not be able to handle all the tasks it has to do.

One way to solve this problem is adding more machines to your system, that is, if you are currently using a single machine to run all your tasks, consider adding another one and split the job. You can split the job between the machines in a number of ways, but I would use a [consumer-producer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) approach.

You will need to use a queue manager where your *producer* periodically sends a batch of tasks to be done (you can still use `whenever` gem for that) and a number of *consumers* (1 makes no sense, 2 would be OK by now but you could increase this number) get the tasks done one by one until there is none left.

The manager I like the most is [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) but you can find some others that might match your needs better.

Comment: You gave a useful keyword for me, I want to say thank you to you

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to ask new questions if needed and use this platform to learn and share your knowledge ;)